# Python.The problem is in solving the problem with cycles

Tags: python, for-loop, cycle

The sum() function takes a series of numbers (a string) and returns their sum.

```
def sum(numbers):
    result = 0
    for num in:
        result += 
    return result

sum("12345")  # 15
```

I started learning the language recently. In one of the sites I came across this problem that I can not solve.

```
def sum(numbers):
    result = 0
    for num in numbers:
        result += 1
```

This is how I see the solution to this problem, but it is not correct.

Comment: Right now you are counting the characters of the input string - for each char you increment the result by 1. Try to figure how to get the digit's value instead.

Comment: `sum` is a built-in function. If you re-declare it by creating your own `sum` function, you won't be able to continue using the original one. It's a good practice not to do it, so in your case, the function name should be `sum_of_digits` or something like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to convert `str` **num** to `int` before adding:

```
def sum1(numbers):
    result = 0
    for num in numbers:
        result += int(num)  # add each number from numbers
    return result

sum1('12345')

#15
```

Comment: Overriding the built-in *sum()* function is not a great idea

Comment: I have changed the name

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum(numbers):
    result = 0
    for num in numbers:
        result += int(num)
    return result
```

the `num` should convert to `int` type

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not define functions that use the same name as a Python built-in function (unless you have a **very** good reason to override it).

In this case you need to convert each character in the string to an integer then sum those integers. You can achieve this as follows:

```
def my_sum(s: str) -> int:
    return sum(map(int, s))

print(my_sum('12345'))
```

**Output:**

```
15
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate on numbers, for each digit which is in str format convert it to int and then sun that to final result.

```
def sum(numbers):
    final = 0
    for num in numbers:
        final += int(num)
    return final
```

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat unclear exactly what you are asking. For one thing, the first function you provide is invalid python, specifically the line:

```
for num in:
```

This needs some collection that you are iterating through after the `in`. The line:

```
result +=
```

is also malformed, it needs a value after the `+=` that will be added to the result. Based off context, I assume you mean the first function to say:

```
def sum(numbers):
    result = 0
    for num in numbers:
        result += num
    return result
```

Also, the way you call the function is incorrect. The value "12345" is not a [list](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) containing the values 1 through 5, but a [string](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings.asp) containing the text "12345". The expression `sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`, using list syntax, will give the correct result of 15.

As for your second implementation of sum, it is also incorrect. Syntactically it is fine, but the line `result += 1` should read `result += num`. By adding only 1 to the result for each element, you are merely counting the number of elements, but to find the sum you must add each element itself.

Comment: OP does not refer to the parameter as a "list". She specifically says it's a "string" - which is correct. What's important is that it's iterable

Comment: Oh, good point, I missed that